# como mostrar los archivos de una carpeta en un website

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, cshtml

Actualmente tengo una app de consola muy simple que me muestra los nombres de los archivos que estan dentro de una carpeta especifica.

```
public void archivoCarpeta()
{
    string carpeta = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["carpetaDescarga"];
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(carpeta);

    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

pero lo que ahora necesito es capturar el nombre y la fecha de los archivos y pasarlo a una vista cshtml y ponerlo dentro de una tabla 
si alguien tiene una idea o un link con un ejemplo para poder guiarme se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla es crear dinámicamente la tabla HTML en tu `codebehind`

**Frontal**

Defines una tabla en tu frontal con `runat="server"` y un `id`:

```
<table id="tblFich" runat="server"></table>
```

**Codebehind (servidor)**

En tu método `archivoCarpeta()` creas dinámicamente la tabla (con sus filas y sus columnas) y asignas el valor del nombre del fichero (`file.Name`) y la fecha de creación (`file.CreationTime.ToString()`)

```
public void archivoCarpeta()
        {
            string carpeta = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["carpetaDescarga"];
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(carpeta);

            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
                HtmlTableCell td = new HtmlTableCell();
                td.InnerHtml = file.Name;
                tr.Cells.Add(td);
                td = new HtmlTableCell();
                td.InnerHtml = file.CreationTime.ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(td);
                tblFich.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
        }
```

**Nota**: estoy suponiendo que ya no vas a tener una aplicación consola si no que vas a trasladar ese código a una aplicación web

Comment: gracias funciono